# Disable the Comments, Recent Post, Archives, section in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, configuration, blogs

There is a section in Wordpress at the bottom of the entry of a post.

This section looks like  [this Image](http://s18.postimg.org/9flmltgs9/Captura.png)

Well, I want to remove that section from every post, and can't find a Wordpress configuration that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

under /wp-content/themes/your_theme/sidebar.php

You will find a div with the next code:

```
   <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
    </div>
```

Just comment (or remove ) the line like this:

```
    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
            <?php //dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
    </div>
```

Also, there are  Plugins that disable comments for all Post or Pages. Like this one: http://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-comments/